# How to count twice in a tuple in SQL?

Tags: sql

[image]

Hi all,
I want to count the total presentation of ID A in this connection table. I wonder how I can count twice in 1 row since ID A is present twice in the first row?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select id, count(*)
from (select id1 as id from t union all
      select id2 from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Some databases support lateral joins.  If you are using such a database, I would recommend a lateral join instead of `union all`.

Answer (score 0):

write a stored procedure with 2 selects and sum they together at the end

```
proc PRSUM

set @x = select count(*) from table where id1 = 'a'
set @y = select count(*) from table where id2 = 'a'

return @x + @y
```

cant remember the exact syntax now as its been a while but that would solve it